# How to instantiate a class from the stack with different constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to create a class instance from the stack, but depending on a variable I need to call it with different constructors

```
  class A
    {
     public:
      A(std::string str);
      A(int value)
    };

void main(void)
{
 bool condition = true;

 A class_a {condtion ? "123" : 456};
   
}
```

But I can't get it to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary operator can't return different types for `true` and `false`.

You could solve it like this:

```
A class_a = condition ? A("123") : A(456);
```

Other fixes:

```
#include <string>

class A {
    public:
    A(std::string str) {} // the function must have an implementation
    A(int value) {}       // the function must have an implementation  
};

int main() {              // not void main
    bool condition = true;

    A class_a = condition ? A("123") : A(456);
}
```